# how to honor the parent logging namespace when importing python modules from entry points

Tags: python, logging, python-2.7, entry-point

I have an application *foo* which iterates over entry points using a group named *foo.modules* . Then it loads any occurrences using the [load()](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/pkg_resources.html#entrypoint-objects) method. This architecture allows writing plugins/modules for the application *foo* and can be found in more details [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pylons-webframework/en/latest/advanced_pylons/entry_points_and_plugins.html).

Also, the application configures some logging handlers when it starts. When I load the plugins however (let's say `foo_plugin`), the logging namespace of the *foo* application is not available in the namespace hierarchy, which leads to warnings like these:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "foo_plugin.plugin"
```

The concept is that whoever writes a plugin can just write:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and the plugin logging should work as the *foo* application dictates.

If I explicitly prepend the *foo* namespace (`foo.`) before the `__name__` variable, the logging works again, but this is not very elegant of course. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is the plugin supposed to know whether it's part of application `foo` as opposed to application `bar`? If you don't want your plugins to be part of the `foo` namespace, you can just attach your handlers to the root logger and you won't get the message about "no handlers could be found".

Comment: They are not supposed to.. you are right. Before experimenting with the entry points I was loading plugins from a sub-package inside _foo_, which of course was honouring the _foo_ logger. That got me confused into thinking that the plugins should too, which is wrong.